# Disable escaping newlines in SQLAlchemy query output

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have newlines `\n` in my MySQL database, and would like my SQLAlchemy query output to NOT escape them to `\\n` when I store part of my query into a string.

```
unexecuted = session.query(Muzzle).filter(Muzzle.executed==False).all()
for x in unexecuted:
    if x.message != None:
        message = 'Line 1\n\nLine 2\n\n'+x.message
        print message
```

If x.message is stored in my MySQL database as `Line 3\n\nLine 4`, then the above code will print:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3\n\nLine 4
```

I can `from string import replace` and do `message = 'Line 1\n\nLine 2\n\n'+x.message.replace("\\n","\n")` to get the formatting I want, but I'd rather not do a replace if I can avoid it. I just want SQLAlchemy to output an unsanitized string. I already sanitize it when I store it into the database (using a php-based frontend), so I don't need it sanitized on the way back out.

Is there any way to change this setting in SQLAlchemy, or modify how I call the functions in such a way that it disables escapes?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I figured it out after a long time of stripping down my code to the bare bones and running packet captures on mysql connections.

The problem was MySQL's default setting of escaping backslashes. It doesn't actually escape the backslash in the transmitted data, there's just a flag in a TCP packet telling the client whether it's supposed to escape the backslashes. So looking at the TCP stream in Wireshark, I couldn't tell anything was wrong on the server end.

Setting `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` on the MySQL server should fix the problem.